# Add image styles with images

Tags: theming, 8, media

I am trying to print an image using an image style that I've created in my drupal 8 theme.

I'm implementing a field template for the field collection. I have an image in my field collection, So i need a way to get the URL for a different image style of the same image.

Any effort will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**mythemename.theme**

```
use Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle;
use Drupal\file\Entity\File;


function mythemename_preprocess_page(&$variables) { 
// change _page to _node or _html depending on the template you are targetting.

  if (isset($variables['node'])) {
    $node = $variables['node'];
    // now you can use $node->field_something

    // Since I have yet to use field collection in D8, I'll let you figure this part out.
    // So all you gotta do is get the fid from your image field.

    // Once you get the FID 
    $file = File::load($fid);
    $uri = $file->getFileUri();
    $url_large = ImageStyle::load('large')->buildUrl($uri);
    $url_medium = ImageStyle::load('medium')->buildUrl($uri);
    $variables['large_image_style_url'] = url_large;
    $variables['medium_image_style_url'] = url_medium;
  }
}
```

Then in twig you can do `{{ large_image_style_url }}` and `{{ medium_image_style_url }}`

I had to do it like this, since I needed to print the image in page.html.twig. If you need yours in node.html.twig you could try the answers to [How to use an image style in a Drupal 8 twig template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33510051/how-to-use-an-image-style-in-a-drupal-8-twig-template)

Answer (score 1):

This post describes how to render images with image styles in Drupal 8 programmatically: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24754661/drupal-8-images-with-image-style

If you want to do it in a twig file here is another example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33510051/how-to-use-an-image-style-in-a-drupal-8-twig-template

Comment: Thanks fons but i have a field collection and an field collection image. please suggest a way to change its image style inside twig.

Comment: Oké, I have update my answer